# Core Data commit notification

Tags: ios, core-data, notifications, commit, nsnotifications

I'm using Core Data in my project and I have to save user-filled forms into Core Data DB. After user relaunches the app, a list of saved forms should show in a TableView. However, if the user exits the app before Core Data commits changes, the form is not saved. Is there any way to catch the moment when my data is commited?

This is how I save the form:

```
if (![document.managedObjectContext save: &error]) {
    NSLog(@"DB saving error!");
}
else {
   NSLog(@"DB save OK!");
   //show alertView
 }
```

I've tried to track the Core Data commit moment using `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`. The log shows that it starts to save the object about 15 seconds later.

```
 // This is how my log output looks like
 2012-08-03 14:50:43.587 iPadAF_new[4506:707] DB save OK!
 2012-08-03 14:50:58.628 iPadAF_new[4506:2597] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

So how can I get the notification or something after the commit, so the user will not be able to exit the app until save?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like you should have to know when the commit occurs. Is the system killing your app before the save happens, or are you just killing it from Xcode?

Comment: Lets say the user decided to kill the app immediately after he/she saw the alert about successfull save

Comment: Frankly, you don't know you have a problem - your just worried you MIGHT have one. May I suggest that you run a test case on a real phone, do as you say - dbl-click the Home button and kill the app as fast as you can - and see if when you restart the data is missing. I suspect its going to work fine - that when the "save" returns successfully that Apple will insure the data is in fact saved. If its not that is a serious Apple bug. Also, do you really think users quit apps all the much? Maybe developers do but "normal" users don't do this so much (they might switch to a different app though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification from your context to find out when the context has been saved, or you can observe KVO notifications for the property `hasChanges`. I doubt those would work for, the background though, so they may not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in the core data templates you should save the context in your AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
     // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application         terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}
```

For me also saving the context in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the commit is when the underlying SQL database commits the contents of the write ahead log to the main file but the write ahead log is kept in a separate persistent file so it should be safe from the moment of db save.

If you inspect the container you will see 3 files for each core data store (at least at some times).

`Foo.sqlite` - The main Database
`Foo.sqlite-shm` - Shared memory/cache file, disposable.
`Foo.sqlite-wal` - The write ahead log. If present and non-empty this contains the latest changes that have not yet been written to the main database but results will still be returned from it if necessary for queries.

This means you shouldn't need to be notified of the commit as the data is already safe before that point, just not coalesced to the main file.